# how to split date start end to array?

Tags: php, datetime, division

If you're using PHP

```
$start = new DateTime('1-1-2017');
$end = new DateTime('4-1-2017');
```

split date to 3

result :

```
array(
  array('start'=> 1-1-2017,'end'=>2-1-2017),
  array('start'=> 2-1-2017,'end'=>3-1-2017),
  array('start'=> 3-1-2017,'end'=>4-1-2017)
);
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this..!!

Use DateTime to iterate dates :

```
$start    = new DateTime('1-1-2017');
$end      = (new DateTime('4-1-2017'))->modify('+1 day');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $dt) {
    echo $dt->format("d-m-y") . "<br>\n";
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply

your answer is static method ,The division number is variable